# AngularJS possible to click all radio buttons

Tags: angularjs, radio-button, angularjs-ng-model, ngmodel

I create a list of radio button selections, but the problem is that when clicked, they both remain selected, thus not working as a radio button group at all.

I have the same ng-model (a string; 'model') and ng-change for all of them, but the id is different.

```
 <div class="radio-button" 
         ng-show="vm.forAdmins" 
         ng-repeat="role in vm.adminRoleDefinitions">

        <input id="{{role.name}}" type="radio"
               ng-model="role.model"
               ng-change="vm.stateChanged(role.name, role.active)" >
         {{role.name}}
    </div>
```

[image]

Been wrestling with this for a while now, can't see what I've missed.

Comment: I see a couple issues: you need a `name` attribute that is the same for all radio buttons - that is what creates the group and allows only a single button to be selected. You don't have a `value` attribute. What will `role.model` be set to when the radio button is selected? How will you select the radio button for a value that has already been set when the view loads?

Comment: @Lex, excellent answer, I was fumbling around without value attribute, you rock.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Radio button will work as a group if you assign name property to those radio buttons. I was also facing this issue then I realized my mistake.

```
<div class="radio-button" ng-show="vm.forAdmins" ng-repeat="role in vm.adminRoleDefinitions">    
            <input id="{{role.name}}" type="radio"
                   ng-model="role.model"
                   ng-change="vm.stateChanged(role.name, role.active)"
                   name="roles" >
             {{role.name}}
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Try assigning a name attribute to your radio button. name groups the radio button. For example :

```
<input type="radio" name="someRadio" id="radioOne" />
<input type="radio" name="someRadio" id="radioTwo" />
```

Now only one is selected at a time.